# Append several identical elements within a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, for-loop

On a particular page, this markup appears several times:

```
<li class= "PRICE">
<label>Total Value:</label>
<span>$2,581</span>
</li>
```

I would like to change it to this dynamically using Javascript:

```
<li class= "PRICE">
<a href="mailto:example@example.com">Additional Savings</a>
</li>
```

While I can do this once, I'm having trouble changing all instances of this markup on the page, because I'm not sure how to create several instances of the same element:

```
var bottomSavings = document.getElementsByClassName("PRICE");
var newLink = document.createElement('a');
newLink.href = "mailto:example@example.com?";
newLink.innerHTML = "Additional Savings";
for (var i = i=0;i<bottomSavings.length;i++) {
    bottomSavings[i].removeChild(bottomSavings[i].children[0]);
    bottomSavings[i].removeChild(bottomSavings[i].children[0]);
    bottomSavings[i].appendChild(newLink);
};
```

What happens is since there is only one "newLink" element, it can only append once. How do I make multiple and append to each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `newLink` element for each item. The easiest way to do this is simply move the code that created your anchor element in to the loop too:

```
var bottomSavings = document.getElementsByClassName("PRICE");
for (var i = i=0;i<bottomSavings.length;i++) {
    var newLink = document.createElement('a');
    newLink.href = "mailto:example@example.com?";
    newLink.innerHTML = "Additional Savings";
    bottomSavings[i].removeChild(bottomSavings[i].children[0]);
    bottomSavings[i].removeChild(bottomSavings[i].children[0]);
    bottomSavings[i].appendChild(newLink);
};
```